# Incrementing a Table Column, and Getting the New Value using ActiveRecord in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, activerecord, codeigniter

I have something similar to the following:

```
$this->db->set('val', 'val+1', FALSE);
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$query = $this->db->update(TABLE_NAME);
```

How can I then go, and get the new value of 'val'? Do I have to do another select, or can I get it off of `$query`?

Answer (score 3):

I've some experience with CodeIgniter and as far as I know you have to requery again.
The update only returns the number of rows affected.

Answer (score 0):

the update query doesnt return anything. if you want to get the value of $val you'll have to run another query

you could run it before running this one, pass the value of val as a parameter to your query next to $id and then return that value + 1.